# I don't understand the need of these conditions. How and when can a linked_list be None?

Tags: python, linked-list, mergesort

(In split function)
I ran it without these conditions, and it worked just as same as with them.
When we get to a single node linked list, the stopping condition of merge_sort function should just return the same single node linked list back and rest can go on.
I saw this in a tutorial and this was explained like " linked_list can be none when a linked_list having a single node is passed through split"
Any help would be highly appreciated

```
if linked_list == None or linked_list.head == None:
    left_half = linked_list
    right_half = None
```

This is the whole program

```
from linked_list import LinkedList

def merge_sort(linked_list):
"""
Sorts a linked list in ascending order
- Recursively divide the linked list into sublists containing a single node
- Repeatedly merge the sublists to produce sorted sublists until one remains

Returns a sorted linked list

Takes O(n log n) time
Takes O(n) space
"""
if linked_list.size() == 1 or linked_list.head is None:
    return linked_list

left_half , right_half = split(linked_list)
left = merge_sort(left_half)
right = merge_sort(right_half)

return merge(left,right)

def split(linked_list):
"""
Divide the unsorted list at midpoint into sublists
Takes O(log n) time
"""
# linked_list can be none when a linked_list having a single node is passed through split
if linked_list == None or linked_list.head == None:
    left_half = linked_list
    right_half = None

    return left_half,right_half

else:
    size = linked_list.size()
    mid = size//2
    mid_node = linked_list.node_at_index(mid-1)

    left_half = linked_list
    right_half =LinkedList()
    right_half.head = mid_node.next_node
    mid_node.next_node = None

    return left_half,right_half

def merge(left,right):
"""
Create a new list that contains the node from left and right
"""
merged = LinkedList()

#fake head to avoid guessing if there is a head in our new linked_list or not
merged.add(0)

current = merged.head
left_head = left.head
right_head = right.head

#iterate over left and right until we reach the tail node of both
while left_head or right_head:
    #if the left_head is None, means we're past the tail node
    # Add the tail node from right to the merged linked list
    if left_head is None:
        current.next_node = right_head
        right_head = right_head.next_node

    elif right_head is None:
        # Add the tail node from left to the merged linked list
        #if the right_head is None, means we're past the tail node
        current.next_node = left_head
        left_head = left_head.next_node

    else:
        #not at either tail node
        #Obtain node data to perform comparison

        left_data = left_head.data
        right_data = right_head.data

        if left_data < right_data:
            current.next_node = left_head
            left_head= left_head.next_node
        else:
            current.next_node = right_head
            right_head = right_head.next_node

    current= current.next_node

#discarding the fake head
head = merged.head.next_node
merged.head = head

return merged
```

And this is the LinkedList program i am importing from

```
class Node:
"""
An object for creating a Node
"""

def __init__(self,data,next_node=None):
    self.data = data
    self.next_node = next_node

def __repr__(self):
    return "<Node: %s>"%self.data

class LinkedList:
"""
A (linear data structure)list to maintain the nodes created
The list refers to the first node as head and each node refers to the next node in the list
"""

def __init__(self):
    self.head = None #an empty LinkedList


def is_empty(self):
    return self.head is None


def size(self):
    """
    if current is none, while loop doesn't run, size return 0
    self.head = current, then we increase count and make current = self.next_node,
    when next_node becomes none, which means current becomes 0, it is past the tail, in that case while loop breaks
    """
    current = self.head
    count = 0

    while current:
        count += 1
        current = current.next_node

    return count


def add(self,data):
    """
    prepends the new date to the LinkedList
    """

    new_node = Node(data)
    new_node.next_node = self.head
    self.head = new_node

def search(self,key):
    """
    Searches the data by trasversing through the list. If not found, it returns None
    """
    current = self.head
    while current:
        if current.data == key:
            return current.data
        current = current.next_node
    return None

def insert(self,data,index):
    """
    Inserts the data at a particular index by trasversing through the LinkedList.
    Inserting is efficient as nothin needs to be shifted but finding and going to the index 
    makes it O(n)
    """
    if index == 0:
        self.add(data)
    if index > 0:
        new = Node(data)
        pos = index
        current = self.head

        while pos > 1:
            current = current.next_node
            pos -= 1

        prev_node = current
        next_node = current.next_node

        prev_node.next_node = new
        new.next_node = next_node

def remove(self,key):
    """
    Removes the first element matching the key in the LinkedList
    returns None if the list is empty or if the key is not in the list
    """
    current = self.head
    prev = None
    found = False

    while current and not found:
        if current.data == key and current is self.head: #if the key is at the head
            found = True
            self.head = current.next_node
        elif current.data == key:
            found = True
            prev.next_node = current.next_node
        else:
            prev = current
            current = current.next_node

    return current

def remove_at_index(self,index):
    current = self.head
    pos = index
    while pos > 0:
        current = current.next_node
        pos -= 1
    self.remove(current.data)

def node_at_index(self,index):
    """
    Returning the node at index by counting the number of times we used next_node on current.
    if it becomes equal to the index, we return the current
    """

    if index == 0:
        return self.head
    else:
        current = self.head
        pos = 0
        while pos < index:
            current = current.next_node
            pos += 1

    return current


def __repr__(self):
    """
    returns a string representation of the list
    """
    current = self.head
    ls = []

    while current:
        if current is self.head:
            ls.append('[Head: %s]'%current.data)
        elif current.next_node is None:
            ls.append('[Tail: %s]'%current.data)
        else:
            ls.append('[%s]'%current.data)

        current = current.next_node
    return '->'.join(ls)
```

Pardon the silly mistakes if any, I am just a beginner.

Comment: `None` is used to represent an empty list.

Comment: linked_list.head==None can represent an empty list but what is the use of linked_list == None

Comment: Just a comment here, a [bottom up merge sort for linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists) is up to 40% faster than top down depending on the size of the linked list and if the nodes are scattered causing a lot of cache misses. I can provide example code in an answer if wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (In split function) I ran it without these conditions, and it worked just as same as with them

If you would remove this code:

```
    if linked_list == None or linked_list.head == None:
        left_half = linked_list
        right_half = None

        return left_half,right_half

    else:
```

... only keeping the code that is in the `else` block, then it will work for all linked lists (also with a list with just one node as you correctly state), **except** when its size is 0:

```
lst = LinkedList()
left, right = split(lst)  # AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next_node'
```

This test code will then fail because `mid_node = linked_list.node_at_index(mid-1)` will assign `None`, as there is no node at index -1. The exception occurs when the code proceeds to evaluate `mid_node.next`.

However, I agree that it makes little sense that `split` would be called with an argument that is `None`. Yet, the code makes this happen by doing this:

```
if linked_list == None or linked_list.head == None:
    left_half = linked_list
    right_half = None   # <--- here
```

This is bad! If we call `split` with a linked list that has no nodes, then we get a different value for `left_half` (empty list) than for `right_half` (`None`)! There is absolutely no good reason why it should do that. `split` should *always* return a pair of linked list instances. So the code should be corrected to this:

```
if linked_list.head == None:
    left_half = linked_list
    right_half = LinkedList()  # <-- create an empty list
```

Now their comment is no longer true: `split` cannot return a `None` list. And so any subsequent call of `split` with the returned values will be getting a linked list instance (not `None`). That whole concept of a `None` list should not be there. An empty list should still be an instance of `LinkedList`.

### Other remarks

`split` mutates the list it gets as argument. In fact, after the call, the *input* list is identical to the *left* list that is returned. This is misleading to the uninformed caller. No mention is made of this in the comments. It would be better if the function were called `splitOffRightHalf` and the function would just return `right_half`. The caller would then know from the name that the original list will be truncated to its left half.

Also, to avoid any discussion about a `None` argument (which really this function should never get), this function should better be a *method* of the `LinkedList` class, and only get `self` as argument. That way it is natural that it is called on an existing linked list instance and no check for `None` needs to be done.

I didn't check the rest of the code, but I stumbled over this comment for the `split` function:

> ```
> # Takes O(log n) time
> ```

This is not true. `split` depends on `node_at_index` which takes O(n) time. This erroneous comment greatly reduces the trust I have in this code.

Comment: Thanks for your response. That answers all my doubts in great detail. And yes, i see that have made an error there. Every split operation incurs a O(k) cost where k here is the midpoint of the list effectively n/2 because i have walk down the list to a particular index , making overall split function O(k log n) and overall code to have O(kn log n). Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Right, but because *k=n/2*, i.e. *k=O(n)*, you should just say *O(n log n)* for `merge`.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, you don't need those conditions in the `split(linkedlist)` function because you are making the check for edge cases in the `merge_sort(linkedlist)` function.
I suppose the tutorial that you referred included it two times to make `split(linkedlist)` work as a standalone function i.e. it will work on any LinkedList.